# Transverse subspace to level set and implicit function theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M^{r+m}$ be a affine space with coordinates $(t^1,...,t^r,z^1,...,z^m)$ and $F:M^{r+m} \to \mathbb C^r$  be a polynomial map which is regular almost everywhere. Let $JF$ denote the Jacobian of this map and  $N$ be the submanifold defined by the vanishing  of the right  $r\times m$ minor of $JF$ i.e. $N:=<\partial_{z^i}F_j=0,\forall i,j>$. Then there exists open dense subset $N_0\subset N$ such that the square  matrix $\partial_{t^i} F_j$ is non-degenerate. Let $q$ be a generic point of $N$, examples at my hand, show that $(t^1,...,t^r)$ can acts as  local coordinates around $q$. I know that at $q$, $JF(q)[\partial_{t^i}]\neq 0$ while $JF(q)[\partial_{z^j}]=0$. Also,
 by implicit function theorem $(z^1,...,z^m)$ will be local coordinates on the level subspace   $L=F^{-1}(F(q))$. I did try to show that $N$ is transverse subspace to $L$ at $q$, i.e. $T_qM=T_qN\oplus T_qL$ but without success. I would like to know your thoughts about this problem.

Regards